# Numeric IDs vs. String IDs

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

*I'm using a very stripped down example here so please ask if you need more context.*

I'm in the process of restructuring/normalising a database where the ID fields in the majority of the tables have primary key fields which are auto-incremented numerical ID's (1,2,3 etc.) and I'm thinking I need to change the ID field from a numerical value to a string value generated from data in the row.

My reasoning for this is as follows:

I have 5 tables; Staff, Members, Volunteers, Interns and Students; all of these have numeric ID's.

I have another table called `BuildingAttendance` which logs when people visited the premises and for what reason which has the following relevant fields:

```
ID    Type    Premises    Attended
```

To differentiate between staff and members. I use the type field, using MEM for member and STA for staff, etc. So as an example:

```
ID    Type    Premises      Attended
1     MEM     Building A    27/6/15
1     STA     Building A    27/6/15
2     STU     Building B    27/6/15
```

I'm thinking it might be a better design design to use an ID similar to the following:

```
ID       Premises      Attended
MEM1     Building A    27/6/15
STA1     Building A    27/6/15
STU2     Building B    27/6/15
```

What would be the best way to deal with this? I know that if my primary key is a string my query performance may take a hit, but is this easier than having 2 columns?

tl;dr - How should I deal a table that references records from other tables with the same ID system?

Comment: If your ID field is a clustered primary key, then having a concatenated string value is a bad idea. check out this article. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/

Comment: In your example, which method do you think makes it easier for you to deal with people who change status from staff to member, or vice versa?

Comment: @DanBracuk, it's very rare that someone will change from member to staff. (i.e. we've only had 3 people do that in the last 2 years.) I''m not sure which is better, I'm just trying to find which one is better for performance.

Comment: I would suggest to first create a table to have relationship between Type and an new column TypeCode (like Staff can be 1, Mem can be 2 and so on) Then use the Type code in your `BuildingAttendance` table.

Comment: If you are restructuring now, why don't create a table Person, with unique id and common attributes, and different (sub)-tables for Staff, Members, etc. with foreign key person id and only proper fields?

Comment: @Renzo, so what you're saying is I should have a top level 'personnel' table with the ID and then have the smaller sub-tables which reference that ID rather then creating convoluted IDs for each table?

Comment: Yes, this should be a good design, so that in the general table you can put a "type" attribute, and then in the BuildingAttendance you put only the foreign key for the Personnel table. This is a standard approach for solutions to problems of this kind.

Comment: Building meaning into primary keys is almost always a bad idea.  Relational databases don't respond well to primary key changes.  Dan Bracuk is right.  When people change their role, or worse, share roles, that risks corrupting your data.  You mention that you are trying to find a solution that is better for performance.  You are looking at it backwards.  Find a solution that is better for **data integrity** and then do what needs to be done _if and when_ you find that you have a performance problem.

Comment: So you've had 3 people change status in 2 years?  That means you have to contend with it.  You might want to change the way you look at things.  Instead of basing your plans on what usually happens, base them on what could possibly happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-incremented numeric ids have several advantages over strings:

- They are easier to implement.  In order to generate the strings (as you want them), you would need to implement a trigger or computed column.
- They occupy a fixed amount of storage (probably 4 bytes), so they are more efficient in the data record and in indexes.
- They allow members to change between types, without affecting the key.

The problem that you are facing is that you have subtypes of a supertype.  This information should be stored with the *person*, not in the attendance record (unless a person could change their type with each visit).  There are several ways to approach this in SQL, none as clean as simple class inheritance in a programming language.

One technique is to put all the data in a single table called something like `Persons`.  This would have a unique id, a type, and all the columns from  your five tables.  The problem is when the columns from your subtables are very different.

In that case, have a table called persons with a unique primary key and the common columns.  Then have separate tables for each one and use the `PersonId` as the primary key for these tables.

The advantage to this approach is that you can have a foreign key reference to `Persons` for something like `BuildingAttendance`.  And, you can also have foreign key references to each of the subtypes, for other tables where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff already provided an answer that points out the type/supertype issue.  I refer to this a class/subclass, but that's just a difference in terminology.

There are two tags in this area that collect questions that relate to class/subclass.  Here they are:

[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)
[shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

If you will look over the info tab for each of these tags, you'll see a brief outline.  Plus the answers to the questions will help you with your case.

By creating a single table called Person, with an autonumber ID, you provide a handy way of referencing a person, regardless of that person's type.  By making the staff, member, volunteer, student, and intern tables use a copy of this ID as their own ID you will facilitate whatever joins you need to perform.

The decision about whether to include type in attendance depends on whether you want to retrieve the data with the person's current type, or with the type the person had at the time of the attendance.